# Visual Studio Command Prompt

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, batch-file

As soon as I open the VS cmd prompt it says "ERROR: Cannot determine the location of the VS Common Tools folder." I'm trying to compile and eventually run my program using a compile.bat and run.bat file.

My program successfully compiled ONCE when I had the following in my compile.bat file:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
FileMgr.sln /rebuild debug
pause
```

After it worked, I tried adding the path of vcvarsall.bat in the variable "Path" in Environment Variables, hoping I wouldn't need that initial call line in the .bat file. This didn't work so I deleted the newly added path from "Path" but now I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can only go wrong if the registry is messed up on your machine or the VS install didn't go well.  The .bat file reads the setting from the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SxS\VS7\10.0 value.  Insert Wow6432Node for a 64-bit operating system.  Double-check with regedit.exe, the SysInternals' ProcMon utility is always handy to troubleshoot registry problems.

Get your machine stable again, ask questions about that at superuser.com.  Try a VS2010 repair to fix the registry first, reinstall next.  Shove it out of a 4th story window if all fails.

Comment: You're right, I added my solution onto another machine and my batch files successfully compile and run the program. I'll probably just re-install VS tomorrow, thank you for your help!